# Function for serialization doesn't see values of checkboxes and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization, bootstrap-modal

I've made custom function for serialization of form inputs. Problem occurs when form is inside a bootstrap modal and checkbox and/or radio buttons returned value is undefined. How can that be? Works well if it's "standard" form i.e when form is not inside a modal. I also checked if particular checkbox/radio button exists which is always true. For text and other type fields presence of a value is not important. They can return an empty string which is fine.

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Update/Izmena</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="container-fluid text-center" style="font-family:Palatino Linotype;">
    <form id="F3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label for="k_ime">Korisničko ime:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="k_ime1" maxlength="30" placeholder="Unesi korisničko ime:" name="k_ime1" value="" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label for="pwd">Šifra:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd1" maxlength="30" placeholder="Unesi željenu šifru" name="pwd1" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label for="ime">Ime:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ime1" maxlength="30" placeholder="Unesi ime:" name="ime1" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label for="prezime">Prezime:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prezime1" maxlength="30" placeholder="Unesi prezime:" name="prezime1" value="" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" maxlength="30" placeholder="Unesi email:" name="email1" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label for="tel">Telefon:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tel1" maxlength="10" placeholder="Unesi telefon:" name="tel1" value="" required>
            </div>
            <?php 

                    $pathTo_file = "/xampp/htdocs/www/knjigovodstvo/install/config.ini";
                    $myfile = fopen($pathTo_file, "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
                    $tekst = fread($myfile,filesize($pathTo_file));
                    fclose($myfile);

                    $arr = explode(",",$tekst);

                    $servername = $arr[0];
                    $username = $arr[1];
                    $password = $arr[2];
                    $dbname = $arr[3];

                    $kon = new SimpleDB($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
                    $sql="SELECT id,kategorija FROM tel_kategorija"; 
                    $result = $kon->execute($sql);


                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        echo "<div class='form-group col-sm-3'><label for='sel4'>Kategorija</label><select id='sel1' class='form-control' name='sel1'>";
                        echo "<option value=''>"."</option>";
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['kategorija']."</option>";
                        }
                    } 
                    echo "</select></div>";

            ?>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label for="jmbg">JMBG:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="jmbg1" maxlength="14" placeholder="Unesi jmbg:" name="jmbg1" value="" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">

            <div class="dropdown col-sm-3">
                <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span>Moduli</span>
                    <span class="caret" id="caret1"></span>
                </button>
                <ul id="comp" class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="adminmodul" id="adminmodul" value="x"> Admin modul</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="ksluzba" id="ksluzba" value="x"> Kadrovska služba</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="esalter" id="esalter" value="x"> E-šalter</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="evidencijaio" id="evidencijaio" value="x"> Evidencija ulaza/izlaza</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="mposlovanje" id="mposlovanje" value="x"> Materijalno poslovanje</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="emagacin" id="emagacin" value="x"> E-magacin</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="blagajna" id="blagajna" value="x"> Blagajna</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="mehanizacija" id="mehanizacija" value="x"> Mehanizacija</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="ekancelarija" id="ekancelarija" value="x"> E-kancelarija</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="submit" style="margin-top: 10px" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="serialization('adminV2.php',this)">Izmeni</button>   
    </form> 
</div>  
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">  
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS: 
First arguments of JS function is pathToFilename+filename.php, second is keyword 'this'.

```
function serialization(phpdoc,me){

    var FormId = me.form.id;

    var name = "";
    var val = "";
    var str = phpdoc+"?";
    var i = 0;

    var net = document.getElementById(FormId).querySelectorAll("#"+FormId+" [name]");
    var len = document.getElementById(FormId).length-1;

    while(i<len) {

        /*if(net[i].type=="checkbox" && net[i].checked===true){
            name = net[i].getAttribute("name");
            net[i].value = "x";
            val = net[i].value; 
        }

        if(net[i].type=="checkbox" && net[i].checked===false){
            name = net[i].getAttribute("name");
            net[i].value = "";
            val = net[i].value; 
        }

        if(net[i].type!="checkbox" && net[i].type!="button"){
            name = net[i].getAttribute("name");
            val = net[i].value;
        }*/

        name = net[i].name;
        val = net[i].value;

        i++;
        str += name+"="+val;

        if(i<len){
            str += "&";
        }

    }

    str = encodeURI(str);
    alert(str);
    str1 = str;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if((document.getElementById("raport")!=undefined || document.getElementById("raport")!=null) && this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("raport").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }

    };

    xhttp.open("GET", str, false);      
    xhttp.send();
    //alert(str);
}
```

You can also see that i've tried checking if button is checked, but besides if this is true or not it value returned is always 'undefined'. PS: Variable str1 is global variable of which is not a concern in this case.

EDIT: This is how it looks for me
[image: This is how it looks for me]

EDIT No.2:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function serialization(phpdoc,me){

    var FormId = me.form.id;

    var name = "";
    var val = "";
    var str = phpdoc+"?";
    var i = 0;

    var net = me.form.querySelectorAll("#"+FormId+" [name]");
    var len = net.length;   
    while(i<len) {

        if(net[i].type=="checkbox" && net[i].checked===true){
            name = net[i].name;
            val = net[i].value; 
        }

        if(net[i].type=="checkbox" && net[i].checked===false){
            name = net[i].getAttribute("name");
            net[i].value = "";
            val = net[i].value; 
        }

        if(net[i].type!="checkbox" && net[i].type!="button"){
            name = net[i].getAttribute("name");
            val = net[i].value;
        }

        i++;
        str += name+"="+val;

        if(i<len){
            str += "&";
        }

    }
    alert(str);
    str = encodeURI(str);

    str1 = str;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if((document.getElementById("raport")!=undefined || document.getElementById("raport")!=null) && this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("raport").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }

    };

    xhttp.open("GET", str, false);  
    xhttp.send();

}
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="iha">
        Text<input type="text" value="" name="ggg1"></br>
        Number<input type="number" value="" name="ggg2"></br>
        blah3<input type="checkbox" value="ttt3" name="ggg3"></br>
        blah4<input type="checkbox" value="ttt4" name="ggg4"></br>
        blah5<input type="checkbox" value="ttt5" name="ggg5"></br>
        <button type="submit" onclick="serialization('izvestaj.php',this)">klik</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT No.3(JS):

```
    function serialization(phpdoc,me){

    var FormId = me.form.id;

    var name = "";
    var val = "";
    var str = phpdoc+"?";
    var i = 0;

    var net = me.form.querySelectorAll("#"+FormId+" [name]");
    var len = net.length;   
    while(i<len) {

        if(net[i].type=="checkbox" && net[i].checked===true){
            name = net[i].name;
            val = net[i].value; 
        }

        if(net[i].type=="checkbox" && net[i].checked===false){
            name = net[i].getAttribute("name");
            net[i].value = "";
            val = net[i].value; 
        }

        if(net[i].type!="checkbox" && net[i].type!="button"){
            name = net[i].getAttribute("name");
            val = net[i].value;
        }

        i++;
        str += name+"="+val;

        if(i<len){
            str += "&";
        }

    }
    alert(str);
    str = encodeURI(str);

    str1 = str;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if((document.getElementById("raport")!=undefined || document.getElementById("raport")!=null) && this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("raport").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }

    };

    xhttp.open("GET", str, false);  
    xhttp.send();

}
```

With this js code works.

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById(FormId)` instead of just `me.form`?

Comment: What is `document.getElementById(FormId).length` supposed to be? `document.getElementById` returns a single element, not a collection, so it doesn't have a length.

Comment: I take it `FormData` isn't useful for you for some reason?

Comment: Are you sure you geetinf FormId currect?

Comment: There's an extra `}` at the end of your JS.

Comment: `var net = me.form.querySelectorAll("[name]"); var len = net.length;`

Comment: @Barmar Incorrect formating when code is pasted. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Smit Raval yes.

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ju992yk4/

Comment: @Barmar I don't know what to say. It doesn't work for me as intended, plus on jfiddle shows values of all checkboxes not just checked one. Truth be told on my side it says 'undefined' for all ...

Comment: If you want just the checked ones, use `if (net[i].checked)`.

Comment: Have you fixed the way you set the `len` variable?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, i used your example. Do i need to edit posted code?

Comment: Single-step through the code in the debugger, to see what the variable values are when it's running.

Comment: @Barmar There are no bugs just warnings that say that input element needs to have autocomplete.

Comment: @Barmar I even made a simpler version. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veljkos82/fcb7qr8v/13/) . It doesn't work even with your suggestion. If i put if (net[i].checked) it also show as if are both checkboxes are checked ... It perplexes me very much ...

Comment: I also want to add that if commented-out code is used and without these two lines name = net[i].name;val = net[i].value; after commented-out code it works. Problem is that are values for checkboxes are now hadcoded ...

Comment: @VeljkoStefanovic Your new fiddle has the incorrect setting of `len`.

Comment: You don't have an `else` in your `if`, so when a box is not checked the variables `name` and `val` still have the values from the previous iteration of `while`.

Comment: In  edit no.2  code works if i use modal. Even don't have to hardcode a value like in previous iteration of it. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veljkos82/85fsf5f7/3/)